# code for jumping the tree instead of dinasour onkeyup in chrome game

Tags: javascript, client-side

[how to jump the tree instead of dinasour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYwdu.png)

I am new to javascript ! code to jump the tree instead of dinasour,can anybody give a solution using chrome?

Comment: You are required to post the code you have and the problem associated it.

Comment: You can check it in your browser with offline

Comment: SO is NOT a coding service. Nobody will code a dinosaur game for you. You must start work on it and ask *small, reproducible* programming issues here. Good luck.